# Asp.Net Use default value in FormView

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, default, formview

I'm new to Entity Framework and Asp.Net in general and I'm trying to figure out how to set a default value for a specific field into a FormView. Here is the basic code:

```
<asp:FormView runat="server" ID="addObjForm"
    ItemType="MySpace.Models.Obj" 
    InsertMethod="insertObj" DefaultMode="Insert"
    RenderOuterTable="false" OnItemInserted="obj_ItemInserted">
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <fieldset>
            <ol>
                <asp:DynamicEntity ID="DynamicEntity1" runat="server" Mode="Insert" />
            </ol>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Insert" CommandName="Insert" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="cancelButton_Click" />
        </fieldset>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

And the code behind:

```
public void insertObj()
    {
        var item = new Obj();
        TryUpdateModel(item);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (WebContext db = new WebContext())
            {
                db.Objects.Add(item);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

Let's say I have to insert data for a child object referencing its father with a foreign key and I pass this foreign key to the web form via GET. How do I automatically set this value into the FormView?

Answer (score 0):

Use ItemCreated event

```
protected void addObjForm_ItemCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (addObjForm.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Insert)
    {
        // Set your default value here by the below sample ways 
    }
}
```

[sample 1](http://forums.asp.net/t/1064910.aspx)

[sample 2](http://forums.asp.net/t/1699186.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but what if my fields are dynamically generated and I don't know the ID of the field I want to set?